# Define dll library path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have project that is using external dll. Dll is located in special path on disc. Visual Studio runs project just in case if I copy dll to project directory, but I need dll to be placed in it's special path. How to tell visual studio project to load dll from that special path?

Comment: Are you using LoadLibrary to load the dll ?

Comment: No, I'm using lib in my project that makes dll load

Answer (score 0):

[SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203(v=vs.85).aspx) :: Adds a directory to the search path used to locate DLLs for the application.

Also, [DLL Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx)::

The SetDllDirectory function supports an alternate search order if the lpPathName parameter specifies a path. 
The alternate search order is as follows:

1. The directory from which the application loaded.
2. The directory specified by the lpPathName parameter of SetDllDirectory.
3. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory. The name of this directory is System32.
4. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched. The name of this directory is System.
5. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

If the lpPathName parameter is an empty string, the call removes the current directory from the search order.

From [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)::
Under Remarks Section, the 8th paragraph advises this,

> The search path can be altered using the SetDllDirectory function.

...

To add the alternate path in your project settings, you can go though this::
[Working with Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx)

> Settings Location = Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment

Ex:: To Add C:\RandomDir to the PATH:

```
PATH=C:\RandomDir;%PATH%
```

Comment: In real installation I will place executable and dll in the same directory. But I need to have dll in separate directory during development. I expect that it is possible to tell VS environment where is dll file.

Comment: have you tried setting Linker->Additional Library Directories ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx

Comment: Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment and Linker->Additional Library Directories doesn't help. I have message "The programm can't start because mydll.dll is missing ..."

Comment: Have you gone through the msdn link regarding settings ? That link have all the settings VS can have regarding library. Or else, call SetDllDirectory and then call LoadLibrary to load it explicitly.